# Does this question belong on BiblicalHermaneutics.SE?

Tags: support, specific-question, migration

Here is [the question](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/34360/does-psalm-8318-deny-the-divinity-of-christ).

Does this one belong in hermaneutics, as it seems to be related to the interpretation of that specific verse, or not? If not, why?

Thanks, I'm just trying to get a better feel for what is and isn't on-topic.

Comment: Why don't you copy and paste the question so it is in the open for all to read, instead of having to click the link. You could also put the question in the title box,
and add that you are asking if it should go to this section?

Comment: @Hello Referencing the original post with a link to main is just fine. In this case the question is not about some aspect of the post that could be quoted but whether the whole thing is appropriate for this site or another. As such is is best reviewed in full in its original context. Anyone who isn't going to review the whole thing probably shouldn't be weighing in with an answer to this anyway. And if they DO have an opinion, they need to have the question open anyway to vote to close, migrate or flag it as appropriate.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It wouldn't be particularly helpful over there in my view as it's fundamentally unanswerable from an analysis of that particular text in isolation without recourse to a **theological framework**.  If you (as you should in this case) are specifying a particular theological framework - eg Trinitarianism - then it would be more appropriate on this site (but as I've commented, it does then become a trivial question).